# How to buy Italian editions of books in Australia?

Tags: australia, shopping

I'm going to stay in Australia for a long period and I really miss reading some book, but I'm not proficient enough to read novels in English.

Is there any Australian (online, most probably) book shop that sells foreign-language editions of popular books/novels? Being Australia such a popular destination for immigrants of any nationality, I'd suppose such a thing to exist. Specifically I'm looking for Italian ones.

I've looked online and I can find some shops of foreign language books, but they're often only educational material or books that were originally published in that language. What I'm looking for instead is popular best sellers that you would for sure find in a local book shop, but in Italian. As an example, where could I buy the Italian edition of an Harry Potter book, or of a George R.R. Martin book?

Of course, an alternative would be to buy a Kindle and e-books, but I'd prefer paper if there exists some way to find books.

If you know any local shop instead of an online one, I'm in the Perth area.

Comment: https://www.amazon.it/Harry-Potter-Saga-Completa-serie-ebook/dp/B01B6RN7DW/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1508359650&sr=1-3&keywords=harry+potter to buy Harry Potter in Italian. I would assume that Amazon delivers from Italy to Australia, it might not be too cheap.

Comment: Book Depository delivers world-wide in numerous languages.  Shipping is included in the sale price.  Using @gnasher729 's Harry Potter example above, here is Book Depository results for Harry Potter in Italian - https://www.bookdepository.com/search?searchTerm=harry+potter&searchTitle=&searchAuthor=&searchPublisher=&searchIsbn=&searchLang=202&advanced=true - Their help page suggests that typical delivery to Australia is 5-8 days. https://www.bookdepository.com/help/topic/HelpId/2/When-will-my-order-arrive

Comment: Yes! That is *exactly* that I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Book Depository](https://www.bookdepository.com/) delivers world-wide in numerous languages.  Shipping is included in the sale price.

Using the *Harry Potter* example, here is Book Depository results for Harry Potter in Italian:

- [Results for Harry Potter - Italian](https://www.bookdepository.com/search?searchTerm=harry%20potter&searchTitle=&searchAuthor=&searchPublisher=&searchIsbn=&searchLang=202&advanced=true)

The help page suggests that typical delivery to Australia is 5-8 days.

> Ships from UK
>   Worldwide
>
> **Australia - 5-8 business days**
>   Singapore & Hong Kong - 5-9 business
>   days
>   New Zealand - 5-10 business days
>   United Kingdom - 2-5
>   business days
>   Ireland - 4-6 business days
>   Europe - 4-8 business
>   days
>   USA - 5-8 business days
>   Canada - 5-10 business days
>   South
>   America - 10-15 business days
>   All other countries - 7-10 business
>   days

Answer (score 0):

Libraries, especially the State Libraries, have foreign language books. Especially in Melbourne. Ask at a library.